# How to define exceptions in scheme using a dynamic variable and abortive control?

Tags: exception, scheme, racket, theory, continuations

I am having trouble implementing exceptions (`handle` and `raise`) using a dynamically scoped variable and `abort`.

This question came from reading the paper [A syntactic theory of dynamic binding](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0030637.pdf), section 6 figure 7.

What I have attempted seems to work correctly for throwing an exception inside a try block and also throwing an exception inside a try block inside a try block.

What doesn't work correctly is throwing an exception from inside a handler. It should abort to the next try block up in this case.

You can see my work here in racket scheme, along with 2 test programs. test-1 is working and test-2 is failing.

```
#lang racket

;; A Syntactic Theory of Dynamic Binding - Luc Moreau
;; https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0030637.pdf

(require racket/control)

(define x_ed (make-parameter 'x_ed))

; NOTE: (abort ..) is the same as (shift k ..) where you don't use k
; NOTE: in (handle f M) we call f the handler and M the try block

; v1
;(define-syntax handle
;  (syntax-rules ()
;    ((handle f M)
;     (parameterize ((x_ed (lambda (v) (abort (f v))))) M))))
; v2
;(define-syntax handle
;  (syntax-rules ()
;    ((handle f M)
;     (reset (parameterize ((x_ed (lambda (v) (abort (f v))))) M)))))
; v3
;(define-syntax handle
;  (syntax-rules ()
;    ((handle f M)
;     (parameterize ((x_ed (lambda (v) (abort (f v))))) (reset M)))))
; v4
(define-syntax handle
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((handle f M)
     (let ((old-x_ed (x_ed)))
       (parameterize ((x_ed (lambda (v)
                              (abort (parameterize ((x_ed old-x_ed))
                                       (f v))))))
         (reset M))))))
(define-syntax raise
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((raise v) ((x_ed) v))))

(define (print x) (write x) (newline))

(define (test-1)
  (print "level-1 open")
  (handle (lambda (v)
            (print "level-1 caught"))
          (begin
            (print "level-2 open")
            (handle (lambda (v)
                      (print "level-2 caught"))
                    (begin
                      (print "level-3 open")
                      (raise #t)
                      (print "level-3 close")))
            (print "level-2 close")))
  (print "level-1 close"))

(define (test-2)
  (print "level-1 open")
  (handle (lambda (v)
            (print "level-1 caught"))
          (begin
            (print "level-2 open")
            (handle (lambda (v)
                      (print "level-2 caught")
                      (raise #t))
                    (begin
                      (print "level-3 open")
                      (raise #t)
                      (print "level-3 close")))
            (print "level-2 close")))
  (print "level-1 close"))

;v1
;> (test-1)
;"level-1 open"
;"level-2 open"
;"level-3 open"
;"level-2 caught"

;v2 and v3
;> (test-1)
;"level-1 open"
;"level-2 open"
;"level-3 open"
;"level-2 caught"
;"level-2 close"
;"level-1 close"

;v2 and v3
;> (test-2)
;...
;"level-2 caught"
;"level-2 caught"
; infinite loop

;v4
;> (test-2)
;"level-1 open"
;"level-2 open"
;"level-3 open"
;"level-2 caught"
;"level-1 caught"
;"level-2 close" <--- we don't want this to happen
;"level-1 close"
```

---

I was able to come up with this working version thanks to the answer:

```
(define-syntax handle
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((handle f M)
     (prompt0
      (parameterize ((x_ed (lambda (v)
                             (control0 k (f v)))))
        M)))))
```

Comment: which variable should be dynamic here?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim x_ed variable is dynamic.

Comment: for a correct implementation you have to check how dynamic-wind is implemented, in combination with call/cc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(**Edit**: I was wrong about being able to make a more space-efficient implementation by using special control operators. It's possible to make the handler run in tail position with respect to the `handle` form, but I don't know of any way to evaluate the body in tail position too.)

<strike>First of all, are you specifically trying to implement exception handling where the body of a `handle` form is in tail position with respect to the `handle` form itself? If not,</strike> there are much more straightforward ways to implement exception handling in terms of simple escape continuations.

<strike>If you really want to implement "safe for space" or "properly tail recursive" exception handling, though, read on.</strike>

<strike>The challenge of implementing `handle` in a safe-for-space manner is that to avoid inserting an extra stack frame into the "no exception raised" path, you need the ability to unwind the stack and resume evaluation with an *expression* in that context. Or equivalently, resume evaluation by calling a procedure in that context. That is different from what `call/cc` provides; it only allows you to unwind the stack and then immediately return a value into that context.</strike>

You can simulate the extra power with `call/cc` at the cost of inserting an extra stack frame (so the body is not in tail position):

```
;; call/cc :       ((Any      -> None) -> Any) -> Any

;; call/cc/apply : (((-> Any) -> None) -> Any) -> Any
(define (call/cc/apply proc)
  ((call/cc (lambda (k) (let ([v (proc k)]) (lambda () v))))))
```

The extra stack frame comes from the application of the result of the `call/cc` expression.

<strike>Can you eliminate the need for that extra stack frame? Yes! But not with `shift` and `reset`.</strike>

The problem you ran into is that `(abort e)` (where `abort` corresponds to Felleisen and Hieb's *A* operator) is **not** the same as `(shift _ e)`. If you look at the [docs for shift and reset](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontrol..rkt%29._reset%29%29), you'll see the following reduction rules:

```
(reset val) => val
(reset E[(shift k expr)]) => (reset ((lambda (k) expr)
                                     (lambda (v) (reset E[v]))))
  ; where E has no reset
```

That is, `shift` does not **remove** its delimiting `reset`, and that stubborn `reset` is what prevents you from jumping out of your level-2 handler straight to your level-1 handler without running `(print "level-2 close")`. You need to pick a delimiter and a control operator that allows you to remove the delimiter.

You cannot do it with `reset` and `shift`.
You cannot do it with `prompt` and `control`.
You can do it with `prompt0` and `control0`.
You can do it with `%` and `fcontrol` (and the right handler).
And of course you can do it with `call-with-continuation-prompt` and `abort-current-continuation` (and the right handler).

Comment: Thank you very much! I found a really good solution using your suggestion of prompt0 and control0. I had not thought about tail calls yet, appreciate you raising this. I tested the implementation and it runs out of space, I'm not sure if it's stack or heap though.

Comment: @rain1 Whoops, I had thought that prompts could either be implemented without extra frames or possibly with some prompt-collapsing tricks that would make them asymptotically irrelevant, but I think I was confusing them with something else. In that case I don't know of any implementation of `handler` better than the one with escape continuations.